# User access to shared folder created on their own pc using destributed file system

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, dfs

I've got a domain model network. I set up DFS (Distributed file system) on a server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Every thing is OK. The problem is here that users using Windows 7 can't access to their shared folder that I created on their computer using DFS. Of course they can access other dfs shared folders.

Comment: What? You used DFS with Shares on Windows 7 computers? I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Sure, why not? You can use ANY share with DFS, it can be linux shares as well... (at least for non replicating DFS). Have a look here for details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753448(v=ws.10).aspx, paragraph "Requirements for servers hosting folder targets"

Answer (score 2):

You need to Enable DFS Loopback Targets:

Registry on the client computers:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Mup\Parameters
```

Create a **DWORD (32-bit)** value named `EnableDfsLoopbackTargets`, and then set the value to `1`.

After changing the value, restart the computer

From: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753448(v=ws.10).aspx

> Although computers running Windows Vista® or Windows® 7 can host
>   folder targets, they are generally unsuitable for use as file servers.
>   In addition to their limit of 10 concurrent incoming SMB connections,
>   computers running Windows Vista or Windows 7 by default cannot
>   navigate a DFS namespace to a folder target hosted on the local
>   computer. For example, if a user on a computer running Windows Vista
>   (\client1) attempts to connect to a DFS folder whose folder target is
>   a shared folder located on the same computer (\client1), the
>   connection attempt will fail. This is considered a loopback
>   connection. This behavior is designed to help prevent a rogue
>   namespace server from redirecting a client computer to an
>   administrative share on the client computer (for example
>   \127.0.0.1\C$), and then reading or writing files in the shared
>   folder.  To allow a client computer access to folder targets located
>   on the local computer (the default behavior on servers), open Registry
>   Editor, navigate to the following location:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Mup\Parameters,
>   create a DWORD (32-bit) value named EnableDfsLoopbackTargets, and then
>   set the value to 1. After changing the value, restart the computer. To
>   disable DFS loopback targets (the default behavior on client
>   computers), set the value to 0. After changing the value, restart the
>   computer.